# Fastest way to find number of lines in go?

Tags: string, performance, go

What I'm using right now:

```
numlines := strings.Count(editor.Text(), "\n")
fmt.Print(strconv.Itoa(numlines))
message.SetText(strconv.Itoa(numlines))
```

This is run whenever a text box is updated. What the most go-like way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is perfectly fine. But don't forget that if the last character is not a newline character, you have to add 1 to the number of occurrences, as that will be the number of lines (the last line may not end with a newline).

What we might think is that since the substring you're counting is only a single character (a single `rune`), we could create a custom solution counting only the occurrence of this single character (instead of counting substrings). It may look like this:

```
func countRune(s string, r rune) int {
    count := 0
    for _, c := range s {
        if c == r {
            count++
        }
    }
    return count
}
```

(A `for range` on a `string` value iterates over its `rune`s.)

And testing it (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Rcj6-Vn-Aq)):

```
fmt.Println(countRune("asdf\nasdf\nasdf\n", '\n')) // Prints 3
```

In practice this won't be faster counting newline characters, as that is a single `byte` in UTF-8 encoding, and [`strings.Count()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Count) is already optimized for counting substrings where the length of the substring is 1:

```
// Count counts the number of non-overlapping instances of substr in s.
// If substr is an empty string, Count returns 1 + the number of Unicode code points in s.
func Count(s, substr string) int {
    if len(substr) == 1 && cpu.X86.HasPOPCNT {
        return countByte(s, byte(substr[0]))
    }
    return countGeneric(s, substr)
}

func countByte(s string, c byte) int // ../runtime/asm_amd64.s
```

What could improve the performance of this operation (counting lines) is if you would have access to the "internal" byte or rune array of the editor, so you would not have to call its `Text()` method, which creates and returns a copy of its content.

Answer (score 4):

When you ask questions about the fastest way, you should measure using the Go [`testing`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/) package benchmark facilities.

For example, count the number of lines in [lorem ipsum](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum) using `strings.Count` and using a `for range` loop over a `string`, and measure any additional cost of converting from a `byte` slice to `string`. You may be able to avoid any `byte` slice to `string` overhead by counting the number of lines in a `byte` slice.

```
$ gotest lines_test.go -bench=.
data: /home/peter/shakespeare.pg100.txt 5589889
BenchmarkStringCount-4     30000000    57.3 ns/op     0 B/op   0 allocs/op
BenchmarkStringByRune-4     3000000   563 ns/op       0 B/op   0 allocs/op
BenchmarkBytesToString-4   10000000   173 ns/op     480 B/op   1 allocs/op
BenchmarkBytesCount-4      20000000    61.2 ns/op     0 B/op   0 allocs/op
```

`lines_test.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "testing"
)

func linesStringCount(s string) string {
    n := strings.Count(s, "\n")
    if len(s) > 0 && !strings.HasSuffix(s, "\n") {
        n++
    }
    return strconv.Itoa(n)
}

func linesStringByRune(s string) string {
    n := 0
    for _, r := range s {
        if r == '\n' {
            n++
        }
    }
    if len(s) > 0 && !strings.HasSuffix(s, "\n") {
        n++
    }
    return strconv.Itoa(n)
}

func linesBytesCount(s []byte) string {
    nl := []byte{'\n'}
    n := bytes.Count(s, nl)
    if len(s) > 0 && !bytes.HasSuffix(s, nl) {
        n++
    }
    return strconv.Itoa(n)
}

var data = []byte(`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, 
sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.`)

func BenchmarkStringCount(b *testing.B) {
    text := string(data)
    b.ReportAllocs()
    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        _ = linesStringCount(text)
    }
}

func BenchmarkStringByRune(b *testing.B) {
    text := string(data)
    b.ReportAllocs()
    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        _ = linesStringByRune(text)
    }
}

func BenchmarkBytesToText(b *testing.B) {
    b.ReportAllocs()
    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        _ = string(data)
    }
}

func BenchmarkBytesCount(b *testing.B) {
    text := data
    b.ReportAllocs()
    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        _ = linesBytesCount(text)
    }
}
```